# How to use font-family in jspdf

Tags: javascript, css, pdf-generation, jspdf, pdfmake

In CSS, we can use font-family to render multi fonts, for example:

```
font-family: Roboto, ZhiMangXing;
```

If Roboto not support, browser will use ZhiMangXing to render the text;

But in [jsPDF](https://github.com/parallax/jsPDF), we can only use setFont api, not font-family;
Is it possible to use font-family in jspdf?
Or is there any hack method to do that?

This is my demo
https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-firefly-jpqtld?file=/public/index.html

In this demo, the webpage render the text correctly with css
The two button download the pdf, but have some font problem

I have tried [pdfmake](https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake), no luck

Comment: @K J, so your idea is to render character one by one: if English character, setFont('A'); if Chinese character, setFont('B')